# Stereo Speaker System - Design Recommendations?

Tags: amplifier, analog

I found that I have two TDA7377A Class AB Audio Amps, and since I got to electronics I always wanted to make my dream amplifier.

My idea is to make a 2 part system, where the first part is the main amp with input selector, bass, treble, volume and balance adjustments, and then a second part which is a graphic equalizer.

### System A: Main Amp

I started looking at the [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/82979/STMICROELECTRONICS/TDA7377.html) of the TDA7377A, and decided that the best option is to have a bridged configuration, since I only have two spare 25W 6 Ohm Philips speakers lying around. The datasheet claims 30W at 4Ohms, so I'm sure that I won't blow those speakers.

Since I also said that I want to be able to adjust the tone, volume and balance, I decided to use the TDA1524. Its [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.es/datasheet-pdf/view/19211/PHILIPS/TDA1524.html) isn't very good, but since there is an application circuit, I will test everithing on a protoboard before proceeding with the pcb design.

I still have to find a suitable input selector IC that meets my requirements, them being:

- The capability to be controlled without a uC (preferrably, with switches).
- Has to have at least 4 inputs.
- Has to be Stereo.
- Has to exist in [this](https://www.celsiusargentina.com.ar/CATALOGOSEMICO.pdf) semiconductor list.*

*That list is the catalogue of my local electronics shop. It isn't necesary that the IC exists in that list, but it makes things easier to get for me.

With that, the main amp would be complete for me.

### Sytem B: Graphic Equalizer

Regarding the System B, I'm still thinking about doing it, mainly because the usfulness of the system given that I cant use a DSP (I dont know how to use them).
My main idea for this system is to have some kind of spectrum analyzer with the available adjustable frequencies. I'm more or less trying to copy the [Technics SH-GE70](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAYmO7UBRBQ&ab_channel=JesuspedronicolasMedina). Having said that, its obvious that the use of a uC is mandatory.

After searching for a while, I've found two suitable ICs that could work: The [TDA7317](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/25123/STMICROELECTRONICS/TDA7317.html), and the [LMC835](https://docs.rs-online.com/da8d/0900766b800a4661.pdf) (both available on the semiconductor list). I'm more tempted to use the LMC835 over the TDA7317, mainly because it has more bands (5 vs 7), per-channel band adjustment and more resolution (7 vs 12 steps).

Having said that, the graphic equalizer would be complete for me.

### Questions

- One thing that I want to know, is if I have to add a preamp or not on the system A. I haven't found a precise explanation to know if I need one or not. Should I use one? If I have to, where should I put it? Keep in mind that I want to use the TDA1524, and maybe have a "pre-out" and "pre-in" to use some kind of EQ.
- What kind of input selector do you recommend? knowing that no microcontroller is going to be used in the system A.
- Do you know about other options when it comes to "semi-analogue" graphic equalizers?

Comment: <<< ... add a preamp or not ... >>> main amp has only 20 db gain. So, if you want to use microphones or something else, preamplifiers are always useful, especially for some characteristics of "special" frequency correction.

Comment: You will get about 20 W for 6 Ohm speakers if you use a TDA7377A design that is limited to 30 W for 4 Ohm. So you are right, your speakers will survive.

Comment: You can easily blow the tweeter in most multi-driver speaker boxes with a sine in the tweeter's range at the nominal wattage of the box: That is a combined rating with most energy expected in the fundamental range

Comment: Alternatives to building a `main amp` include *activating* the boxes. Crossover options include "active" analogue as well as digital - #[Linkwitz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkwitz%E2%80%93Riley_filter).

Comment: @Antonio51 well, I don't really plan on using microphones, it's a relatively low power amp. Having said that, and "...special frequency corrections.", Can you give me some advice on where to put the preamp? And how to design one maybe? Thanks!

Comment: @greybeard don't worry, there are only one speaker per box. (If you want to check out, google Philips MCD135). Also, regarding "...activating the boxes...". I don't understand that. Why should I do that, and where should I use those Linkwitz filters?

Comment: RIIA curve, something like this: https://www.instructables.com/RIAA-Equalization-with-analog-electronics/

Comment: Activating a single driver box is less attractive than a, say 3-way system. One reason to activate a (k bucks) speaker box is not to pay serious bucks for a power audio cable. One would use a Linkwitz-Riley filter in the ("active") crossover.

Comment: @Antonio51 Oh, then I dont think I should bother making one. This amp is probably going to be connected to the audio out of a tv, maybe to some cd player and it will have a bluetooth receiver inside.

Comment: (4" driver in a 5 litre OD enclosure - what would you want a multi-digit Watts amp for?)